# NHibernate, non composite ID and GetHashCode

Tags: nhibernate, gethashcode

When my domain model have a composite key in the database I will get an exception when forgetting to override Equals/GetHashCode

```
NHibernate.MappingException: composite-id class must override Equals():
```

Why does it not give me the same error when I have a non composite ID?

Answer (score 3):

NHibernate uses the primary key value of your class in its internal state-tracking engine to identify that instance.

When you have a single primary key property in your domain, NHibernate will use the value returned by the property as the key value, calling `GetHashcode` and `Equals` on the value, using the primary key much like you would use it in a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` instance.

When there are multiple primary key properties forming a composite key, NHibernate has no trivial way to get a key value it can use. It requires you define how to determine equality between two instances, effectively turning the instance into its own key much like it would be in a `HashSet<T>`.

If you haven't overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on your type to use your composite key values, it does not reflect the "equality" used by the data-model (two rows being equal if they have the same primary key) and NHibernate cannot be certain it is tracking the correct entities; this is why the exception occurs.

You can find out an overview of composite keys and more information on clever ways to deal with them [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2010/06/30/nhibernate-and-composite-keys.aspx).

Comment: I see. NH uses the mapping to find the property for a single primary key and gets the hascode on this. This is OK, since it is a simple type and have a well defined hash code. But couldn’t' it do the same for composite keys, or will the “computed” hash code be too weak?

Comment: .. and how can NH use HashSet<T> when dealing with single primary keys and Equals/GetHashCode has not be overridden?

Comment: You can imagine that NHibernate uses a `Dictionary` when you have a simple primary key, with the key being the primary key value, and a `HashSet` when there is a composite key used. It is possible that NHibernate could create an internal type to contain the primary key values, but currently it does not.

Comment: That's my point. If it uses a Dictionary for a simple primary key why not do the same for the composite key so we don't need to write equals/hashcode

Comment: Okay, but you would have to express some way of determining equality and the hash code; NHibernate could try and guess a way of doing this depending on the types used, but there is no foolproof way of handling this situation without some kind of configuration. NHibernate obtains that "configuration" through a custom implementation of `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.